# Java version error after upgrading a dependency

Tags: java, maven, wro4j

I'm trying to upgrade my wro4j dependency from 1.7.x to the latest (1.10.1).

My project uses Java 8.

I didn't see anywhere (documentation or otherwise) that wro4j requires a specific java version to run, however, when I change the version in my pom.xml and try to compile my project, I receive the following error:

> Execution default of goal `ro.isdc.wro4j:wro4j-maven-plugin:1.10.1:run` failed: Unable to load the mojo `'run'` in the plugin `'ro.isdc.wro4j:wro4j-maven-plugin:1.10.1'` due to an API incompatibility: `org.codehaus.plexus.component.repository.exception.ComponentLookupException`: `ro/isdc/wro/maven/plugin/Wro4jMojo` has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 53.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0

Does this mean that I can't upgrade to 1.10.1 without first upgrading Java, or is there another solution?

Comment: No, not really. I have figured out by myself that it's related to a java version mismatch (it's part of my question), but my question is rather why that is, and how to fix it.

Comment: A comment on their github suggest you'll possibly run into this again - https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-petclinic/pull/707

Comment: Yes you can&#39;t upgrade it unless you upgrade your java version or you compile your dependency yourself with java 8 yourself (which would require code changes as well)